# Sencha 2.0 and Codeigniter RESTful API generates Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, json, api, codeigniter, sencha-touch

I am trying to feed sencha with (JSON) data generated from codeiniter restful api. I did the the RESTful API based on the  [Net.tuts CI API TUTORIAL](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/)

I get the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Here is my Sencha code and CI Code

**CI CODE**

```
function user_get()
    {
      if(!$this->get('id'))  
      {  
            $this->response(NULL, 400);  
      }  

        $user = $this->user_model->get( $this->get('id') );  

        if($user)  
        {  
            $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code  
        }  

        else  
        {  
            $this->response(NULL, 404);  
        }     
    }
```

**GENERATED JSON**

```
{
name: "ALEX JOHN",
country: "USA",
city: "NY"
}
```

**SENCHA CODE**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    launch: function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {

    fullscreen: true,
    store: {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: ['name', 'country','city'],

        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://localhost/rest_api/index.php/users/user/id/2',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            callback: function(result) {
              console.log(result)  ;
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    },

    itemConfig: {
        tpl: '<p>{city}</p>'
    }
});
    }
});
```

I cannot figure out where the area comes from. Is it from my JSON Data format?How sencha is consuming it? Kindly someone help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're requesting JSONP, youll need to wrap your returned JSON in a callback.  In your controller, try replacing your valid response with:

```
//Is the GET field callback set?  If so, wrap the user object in it
if (isset($_GET['callback'])){
  $user=$_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($user).')';
  //And manually create the response 
  header("Status: 200 OK"."\r\n");
  header("Date: ".gmdate(DATE_RFC822)."\r\n");
  header("Content-Type: application/javascript charset=UTF-8\r\n");
  header("Content-Length: " . strval(strlen($user))."\r\n");
  echo $user;
} else  //Use thhe API to gnerate the response as normal
$this->response($user, 200);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had to echo $user in the if clause as the return value after the headers. I got a better results.No errors now but there is no output returned on the browser.Following my research on the net I find that we are now correct on how we are passing data.In my Sencha DataView, do you think I am handling the data in the right way. I am faily new in sencha. Thanks a bunch.